# Verbatim environment with background color (PDFLaTeX and tex4ht)

Tags: pdftex, color, verbatim, backgrounds, tex4ht

I need to make a verbatim environment with gray background color, such as:

[image: colored background verbatim envrionment]

That needs to work with PDFTeX and tex4ht on an older TeX installation (from 2009 I believe). My approach so far is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed,color,verbatim}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\snugshade\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endsnugshade}


\begin{document}
text

\begin{code}
line one
line two
\end{code}


\end{document}
```

which works when I run it with `pdftex main.tex`. But when I give the command `htlatex main xhtml,4,next` I get errors:

```
(/opt/texlive2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)) (./main.aux)
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.17 \end{code}

? 
! Emergency stop.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.17 \end{code}

No pages of output.
```

What can I do to get the custom gray background verbatim environment as in the example (called "code") with PDFTeX and tex4ht with TeXlive from 2009?

Comment: If there was room for another tag, [tag:obsolete]  would be appropriate.

Comment: Why not using `listings`? It should contain support for background colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to check if I need the PDF or the HTML document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf,verbatim}

\ifpdf
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\snugshade\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endsnugshade}

\else

\newenvironment{code}
    {\HCode{<div class='code'>}\verbatim}
    {\endverbatim\HCode{</div>}}

\fi

\begin{document}
text

\begin{code}
line one
line two
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19):

The credits should go to Martin Scharrer. It is possible with the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,color}

\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}

\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible}}{}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\begin{document}
text

\begin{code}
line one
line two
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

This document works with `tex4ht` and `pdftex`.

Comment: do you need that `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}` line?

Comment: @mangledorf probably not

Comment: is it possible to make this put the gray backgroup that extends only up to the text inside? instead the whole width of the page? Similar to the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141100/getting-verbatim-with-soft-grey-background-as-in-tex-stackexchange)  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is to use `tex4ht` hook system.

Put the definition of the environment to the `code.sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mycode.sty}
\RequirePackage{framed,color,verbatim}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\snugshade\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endsnugshade}
```

then create file `code.4ht` which is called only with `tex4ht`:

```
\renewenvironment{code}{\:tempa\verbatim}{\endverbatim\:tempb}
\ConfigureEnv{code}{\HCode{<div class="code">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{.code{
border:1px solid black;
background-color: \#999;
}}
```

you need to redefine `code` environment, remove code that cause problems and put hooks `\:tempa` and `\:tempb`. Configurations from `\ConfigureEnv` will be inserted here.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get an error during processing: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \Verb:N` This may have to do with the quirks of verbatim. Is your solution supposed to work out of the box? I am using Texlive 2013 and the tex4ht version it provides.

Comment: @stefano I have access only to TeXlive 2012 at this moment, compilation is without problems

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can always use `adjustbox` to add the background color. Here you have to be careful not to take the `\begin{adjustbox}{..}` form but the `\adjustbox{..}\bgroup .. \egroup` form. I added some padding and margin.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}

\newenvironment{code}%
   {\par\noindent\adjustbox{margin=1ex,bgcolor=shadecolor,margin=0ex \medskipamount}\bgroup\varwidth\linewidth\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endvarwidth\egroup}

\newenvironment{code2}%
   {\par\noindent\adjustbox{margin=1ex,bgcolor=shadecolor,margin=0ex \medskipamount}\bgroup\minipage\linewidth\verbatim}%
   {\endverbatim\endminipage\egroup}


\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\begin{code}
line one
line two
\end{code}

text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\begin{code2}
line one
line two
\end{code2}


text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Mmm, for `htlatex` this adds `__` with the final `minipage`/`varwidth` width at the beginning of the `line one`. I'm trying to fix this.